With TypeScript, how can you augment the type of `window` without affecting the global Window type used by other libraries and iframes?
Is there a way to augment the type of the global window object without changing the Window interface that's used for windows in other contexts.
For example, can I change the type of window without affecting the type of the object returned by someIframeElement.ownerDocument.defaultView? Similarly, can I change the type of the global window without affecting the Window type referenced by types provided by module dependencies I've included in my package?
the window object is defined by TypeScript's lib.dom files like so:
declare var window: Window & typeof globalThis;

I've been doing this to add custom property types in my application, to provide types for the properties I'm manually defining.
declare global {
  interface Window {
    myCustomProperty: number
  }
}

window.myCustomProperty = 123;

This worked well, but my application interacts with the document inside of an <iframe>, and I want to separate the types for the different sets of properties that are added to the global window and those added to the iframe's window.
i.e.
declare function getFrameElement() : HTMLIFrameElement;

// No TS error, which is what I want.
console.log(window.myCustomProperty)

// I want TS to error here, because the `iframe` window should not have the same type as the global window.
console.log(getFrameElement().contentDocument.defaultView.myCustomProperty);

I know that I could solve this by casting the window object manually, but is there any solution that would work without needing to manually apply my CustomWindowType type everywhere, and without using an extra utility function just to return the window as a custom type?
// This would work, but I want an option that doesn't require casting
(window as CustomWindowType).myCustomProperty;

// This could also work, but just moves the casting into a util.
function getCustomWindow() { return (window as CustomWindowType); }
getCustomWindow().myCustomProperty;


I found my answer from this other post: Using globalThis in Typescript
The short version is that if you declare variables within declare global { } using var instead of const or let, then they will be defined on the window object without affecting the Window interface.
i.e.
declare global {
  var myCustomProperty: number;
}

const globalWindow = window;
const frameWindow = getIFrameElement().contentDocument.defaultView;

console.log(globalWindow.myCustomProperty) // No TS error, number type
console.log(frameWindow.myCustomProperty) // ERROR: not defined on the frame window

